# NewRelic get Browser Javascript for Browser Monitoring

Tags: javascript, newrelic

I have currently started using New Relic at work for one of our applications. I added the javascript to live to test if browser monitoring worked and it was working fine but then shortly after a deploy was made and that file got removed so now I don't have the javascript that I need to copy and paste for that application.

Is there a way to recreate the browser monitoring or can I click something to get the Javascript for that app again?

Thanks, very new to New Relic.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by deleting the application from newrelic, waiting 10 minutes, restarting the APM agent and then adding the application again and recreating browser monitoring. Thanks